# Динамическая кнопка для CSS

Tags: html, css

Ребята, помогите пожалуйста разобраться, создал кнопку для сайта.

```
<style type="text/css">
a.button {
  width: 191px;
  height: 189px;
  display: block;
  float: left;

  text-decoration: none;
  background: url(images/start-game.png) top right no-repeat;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
}

a.button:hover {
  background-position: 100% -189px;

}

</style>
<p><a href="" class="button" onclick="this.blur(); return false;"></p>
```

Когда на странице лишь этот код, то все работает нормально, а когда добавляю данный код на сайт, то появляется целых 3 таких кнопки.

Сменил имя результата никакого, вот результат firebug

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
<div id="logo">
<style type="text/css">
<p>
<a class="button" href=""></a>
</p>
<a class="button" href=""> </a>
</div>
<a class="button" href="">
</div>
<a class="button" href="">
</body>
</html>
```

Почему-то повторяются строки с классом батом, а в моем исходном коде она одна.

Comment: Больше информации, сайт статический или пишете на каком-то языке/фреймворке?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, у Вас проблема в том, что код дублируется в php, циклы или как-то еще на серверной стороне.

Проверяйте исходный код через браузер. А мне через хром нравиться отлаживать.
Правой кнопкой мыши по элементу страницы и в контекстном меню пункт "Просмотр кода элемента"

И еще попробуйте использовать другое имя класса. Менее очевидное. Может по этому классу обращаются JS скрипты.

Comment: Хром более "мягко" воспринимает огрехи, нежели огнелис - из личного опыта. А вообще да, отладка в любом браузере хороша(не понимаю, почему её ругают в опере?)

Comment: посмотрите в верху результат firebug

Comment: а мне через оперу нравится отлаживать)

Comment: приблизительно одиноково что в хроме что в опер. firebug не пробовал. мне вообще не нравится firefox

Comment: firefox убого медлен, очень медленный в перерисовке...<br>Firebug конечно крут но не настолько чтобы ради него сидеть и нервничать :)<br>я тоже юзаю хром....

Answer (score 0):

Открываете отладчик(тот же firebug в firefox) и смотрите, откуда появились ещё две кнопки.

Comment: поставил firebug, но разобраться не удалось(